# When (if ever) does QueryPerformanceCounter() get reset to zero?

Tags: winapi, timing

I can't find any clear indication of if/when the 64-bit value returned by QueryPerformanceCounter() gets reset, or overflows and resets back to zero. Hopefully it never overflows because the 64 bits gives space for decades worth of counting at gigahertz rates. However... is there anything other than a computer restart that will reset it?

Comment: There is no scenario where you *ever* care about this.  You can only ask practical questions here.

Comment: That's a bit arrogant, surely? have you ever heard of eliminating lines of enquiry?

Comment: Of course not, you didn't put them in your question.  It is completely unclear what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: It's a really simple and clear question. The reason you never care about it is presumably because you know with certainty that QPC() behaves in a certain way with regard to being reset. Well stop criticising the question, and share that certain knowledge, because it is hard to find. Is QPC reset by hardware? By the OS? Does it provide a strictly read-only interface, or are there (undocumented) ways to reset the counter and screw things up? Etc.

Comment: It's not documented that the counter can be reset by anything other than the implied 64-bit overflow. If it's not documented you can assume it doesn't do it (because if it did, all sorts of things would break because everyone else assumes it doesn't do it).

Comment: Assuming you're asking because you're getting strange results from QPC, it was possible to get inconsistent results depending on what CPU the thread making the call was running on (i.e. the counter was consistent on each core, but not consistent between cores).  It was also possible to get bogus results on systems that varied the CPU clock.  However, I've not seen either of these problems in recent years.  If you're running moderately recent Windows on moderately recent hardware QPC should be OK.

Comment: I was getting strange results from code that used QPC, but which had other stuff going on too. I wanted to rule out any possible reset in QPC as a possible cause. I searched for "QPC reset" and "QPC zero" and found absolutely nothing, apart from unanswered questions - does QPC reset across a standby or hibernate, for example. I thought it was a pretty simple question, and I made sure that it had obvious searchable keywords in it. I'm just amazed at the reluctance of anyone to answer the question clearly. Does anyone even know for sure?

Comment: That said, I subsequently found my own bug elsewhere, so I'm not hanging out for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Empirically, QPC is reset at system startup.

Note that you should **not** depend on this behavior, since Microsoft do not explicitly state what the "zero point" is for QPC, merely that it is a monotonically increasing value (mod 2^64) that can be used for high precision timing.

Hence they are quite within their rights to modify it's behavior at any time.  They could, for example, make it return values that match `FILETIME` values as would be produced by a call to `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`, with the same resolution, 100ns tick rate.  Under these circumstances, it would never reset.  At least not in your or my lifetimes.

That said, the following program when run on `Windows 10 [Version 6.3.16299]` produces pairs of identical values that are the system uptime in seconds.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER performanceCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER performanceFrequency;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&performanceFrequency);

    for (;;)
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&performanceCount);
        DWORD const systemTicks = timeGetTime();
        DWORD const systemSeconds = systemTicks / 1000;
        __int64 const performanceSeconds = performanceCount.QuadPart / performanceFrequency.QuadPart;
        std::cout << systemSeconds << " " << performanceSeconds << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Standard disclaimers apply, your actual mileage may vary, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: as of writing this comment I've made a test and it indeed looks like the counter is reset on startup, because after a reboot the value is smaller than the value before the reboot

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some Windows running inside VirtualBox may reset QueryPerformanceCounter every 20 minutes or so: [see here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11951#comment:2).

QPC is more reliable as time goes by, but for better portability a low precision timer should be used such as [GetTickCount64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).